# How to determine if a Google Cloud Storage blob is marked "share publicly"?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

The Google Cloud Storage bucket browser UI has a checkbox titled "Share publicly" which makes a blob downloadable by anyone.

The [Python API](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/storage/blobs.html) has a way to check that box using `make_public()` (but not uncheck), and to get the resulting link using `public_url()`. It doesn't have an `is_public()`.

How can you find out if a blob is publicly accessible?

Answer (score 3):

The closest I managed is

```
is_public = "READER" in blob.acl.all().get_roles()
```

which works, but it doesn't look like an official method. The string `READER` comes from a private constant, so may change in the future. Also `blob.acl` isn't documented as a way to fetch access control lists, only to create them.

So this works, but isn't very satisfactory.

Comment: Reading the documentation at https://gcloud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/storage-blobs.html, I think one interpretation of blob.acl() "creating" the access control list, is that it is creating the ACL object representing the stored permissions (e.g. to fetch and interpret the settings), rather than creating the permissions themselves. I agree the wording doesn't make that clear.